# Bullet Proof Way To Tell If the Device Is A Mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mp4, detect

I need to be able to load some mp4s but only make them available if the device is a mobile.

I am currently using.

```
var IsMobile = false;
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
IsMobile = true;
}
```

Which works great but users can just open safari and click developer user agent select iphone ipad or anything and then my app will serve the mp4 links which they can use web inspector to download.

Is this even possible or will i need to find another work around?

Pretty sure this is not possible...

Thanks

Comment: if this was possible , then the next release of the browsers would do something to spoof that as well for proper mobile testing

Comment: true ok i guess i find another work around